# Regarding conditions required and specific topology to be induced on borel sets to define a specific measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I am trying to solve assignment problems of an institute in which I don't study as our faculty doesn't  gives assignments and  I'm unable to think about how to proceed through this particular problem.

Problem is ----- Define extra conditions on Borel sets and also tell the underlying topology on borel sets, so as to extract a measure such that $ \mu $ (E) = 0 for every Borel Set E in the topology induced?

I have studied First two chapter of Walter Rudin real and complex analysis and GB Folland a guide to advanced real analysis but I could not think about how to solve this.

Please give some hints.

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva can you please  help me in this question?

Comment: @pre-kidney can you please help me in  this question, you already have helped me in some questions of measure theory. Can you please give some hints if you have some time to spare?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy . Sir ,  You have answered many questions asked by mein measure theory. Can you please have a look if you have some spare time. I really need help.  Despite so many days I can't get any answer on this site and I couldn't made any significant progress on this problem. The instructor  under which I am taking this course doesn't even take doubts.